# Постраничный вывод данных из БД

Tags: php, mysql

> Доброе утро. Делаю постраничный вывод данных из базы.
>
> Имеется вывод строк из БД, нужно разбить по страницам.

```
<center><table>
    <?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `statmoney`") or die(mysql_error());

    while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $base = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($base);

        if($row[0]==0){
            echo "empty";
        }else{
            echo"<tr>
                <td><b>".$stats['date']."</b></td>
                <td><b>".$stats['msg']."</b></td>
                <td><b>".$stats['num']."</b></td>
            </tr>";

    $row = mysql_num_rows($query);
        }
    }
    ?>
    </table></center>
```

**Пробую выполнить это таким способом:**

```
<center><table>
<?php

$num_elements = 2; /* Кол-во данных на страницу */

if (empty(@$_GET['page']) || ($_GET['page'] <= 0)) {
$page = 1;
} else {
$page = (int) $_GET['page']; // Считывание текущей страницы
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`") or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query); /* Кол-во данных */
$num_pages = ceil($rows / $num_elements); /* Кол-во полученых страниц */

// Если номер страницы оказался больше количества страниц
if ($page > $num_pages) $page = $num_pages;
$start = ($page - 1) * $num_elements; // Начальная позиция, для запроса к БД

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` LIMIT ".$start.", ".$num_elements);

while ($stats = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $base = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table`");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($base);

    if($row[0]==0){
        echo "empty";
    }else{
        echo"<tr>
            <td><b>".$stats['date']."</b></td>
            <td><b>".$stats['msg']."</b></td>
            <td><b>".$stats['num']."</b></td>
        </tr>";

$row = mysql_num_rows($query);
    }
}
?>
</table></center>
```

> Это только набросок, так как опыта работы с MySQL пока не имею.
>
> Как вывести ссылки пока не пойму ))
>
> Поправьте пожалуйста или укажите на ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Влом разбирать твой код, так что приведу свой рабочий пример вывода записей с постраничной навигацией.

```
$page=(isset($_GET["page"]))?$_GET["page"]:1; //Задаем номер открытой страницы

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NameTable"); //Запрашиваем число записей

$ResultCount=mysql_result($result, 0); //Получаем число записей

$PagesCount=intval(($ResultCount - 1) / $ЧислоЗаписейНаСтранице) + 1; //Узнаем число страниц

$sql = "SELECT *  FROM NameTable ORDER BY ПолеСортировки ASC (DESC) LIMIT ".($page * $ЧислоЗаписейНаСтранице - $ЧислоЗаписейНаСтранице).", ".$ЧислоЗаписейНаСтранице; //Запрос записей, которые необходимо вывести на странице с активным номером.

$Rows = mysql_query($sql);
while($R = mysql_fetch_assoc($Rows)) {
//Выводим
}
```

Ну и остается только вывести ссылки навигации. Вариантов, форм и прочего тут может быть куча. Приведу такой пример:

Функция выводит максимум 10 номеров, при этом всегда выводит последний.

```
function Navigation($page,$pages) {
    $n='';
    if($pages>1){
        $n.='<div class="pages">';
        if($pages <= 9) {
            $start = 1;
            $end = $pages;
        }
        else {
            if(($page - 4) < 1) {
                $start = 1;
                $end = 9;
            }
            elseif(($page + 4) > $pages) {
                $end = $pages;
                $start = $pages - 9;
            }
            else {
                $start = ($page - 4);
                $end = ($page +4);
            }
        }
        for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i++){
            $n.='<a href="/script.php'.(($i != 1) ? '?page='.$i : '').'"'.(($page == $i) ? ' class="selected"' : '').'>'.$i.'</a>';
        }
        if($end < $pages) {
            if($end != ($pages - 1)) $n.='<span>...</span>';
            $n.='<a href="/script.php?page='.$pages.'">'.$pages.'</a>';
        }
        $n.='</div>';
    }
return $n;
}
```

Comment: Первую строку почемуто не ныводит.
    А как вызывать функцию?

Comment: Выводить должен всё. Функцию просто отправить на вывод:
echo Navigation($page,$PagesCount);